# Java - How to wait for an instance to finish before proceeding

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I'm trying to wait for a piece of code to return true before I proceed with everything else. I have two classes, each has one instance running.

**Main** where I open the new object I want to wait for to complete

```
setupWizard setup = new setupWizard();
setup.setVisible(true);
setup.setCallerRef(new java.lang.ref.WeakReference(this));

synchronized(this) {
    while (setup.isItComplete() == false) {
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

ArrayList<String> accounts = Functions.fetchAccounts();
```

**SetupWizard** i want to wait for

```
public setupWizard() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    //get handlers
    JButton helpBtn = (JButton)getContentPane().getComponent(9);
    JButton saveBtn = (JButton)getContentPane().getComponent(8);
    JTextField userName = (JTextField)getContentPane().getComponent(3);
    JTextField serverField = (JTextField)getContentPane().getComponent(1);
    JPasswordField passwordField = (JPasswordField)getContentPane().getComponent(5);
    JScrollPane scrolly = (JScrollPane)getContentPane().getComponent(7);
    JLabel customQLabel = (JLabel)getContentPane().getComponent(6);
    scrolly.setVisible(false);
    customQLabel.setVisible(false);

    //theb change btn positions and action listeners
    setBounds(100, 100, 435, 220);
    changeHelpButton(helpBtn);
    helpBtn.setEnabled(false);
    changeSaveButton(saveBtn, userName, serverField, passwordField);
    registerAccount("hi", "hi");
} 
public void registerAccount(String pass1, String pass2) {
    if (pass1.equals(pass2)) {
        Functions.addToDatabase("admin", pass2, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
    setComplete(true);

    synchronized(getCallerRef()) {
        getCallerRef().notifyAll();
    }

    dispose();
}

private boolean complete = false;
private Object callerRef;

public boolean isItComplete() {
    return this.complete;
}

public void setComplete(boolean variable) {
    this.complete = variable;
}

public void setCallerRef(Object mycaller) {
    this.callerRef = mycaller;
}

public Object getCallerRef() {
    return this.callerRef;
}
```

As you can see this is only the relevant section of the code. However, what happens is the Main thread freezes, but the second UI that should pop up is just a see-through window with nothing on it. What might be the problem? Or is there any other viable approach to "block code until x becomes true"?

**Edit:**

Ok I think i figured out a problem with this; if i just initialise the class, and then immediately call registerAccount() from the initialiser method of the second class without trying to do anything with the UI, it works. However, I don't immediately want to go to registerAccount(), because before then there is a semi-long procedure the user has to go through to input all sorts of data, after which the main us has to be unfrozen. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `CountDownLatch` instead of boolean. Then you can just do `cdl.await()` instead of a busy-waiting loop.

Comment: Don't put too much into a setup wizard.  I'm sure your making great code and it will only be setup once.

Comment: i've tried with countdown latches and I bump into the same problem, where my window is completely seen-through with no components on it what so ever:( at this point i think there is a problem with how the ui is created rather than the threading itself, but i dont really know honestly
@danny117 this is for the initial setup! :)

Comment: @peterxy There are many issues with your code. 1.You need to have separate thread calling the registerAccount so that notifying thread is different from the waiting thread. 2. Your constructor invokes currently the registerAccount which tries to synchronize on the lock objct but you pass the lock object from main after contructor is invoked. 3. your object on which you wait and on which you invoke notifyall are different objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using wait() correctly, but it could be very useful in doing what you'd like to do.

First, read the javadoc on Object.wait

Then, in your code where you are currently calling

`this.wait()`

change this to

```
synchronized (setup) {
  setup.wait();
}
```

In setup, change `setComplete` to

```
public synchronized void setComplete(Boolean variable) {
    this.complete = variable;
    if (variable) {
      this.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

This is the basic framework (there's plenty built on top) of how you do efficient multithreaded locking / waiting / synchronizing

Comment: Thanks for your input! This results in java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException :(

Comment: @peterxz sorry I forgot to `synchronized` around setup before calling setup.wait. I have fixed this

Answer (score 0):

There are two different objects, the notifyAll you invoke is on the `WeakReference` object where as you wait on the object of `Main`.

In the `registerAccount` method of `setupWizard` class you need to do changes as below so that you notify on the same object as the object upon whose lock Main thread is waiting.

```
Object lock =   ((WeakReference)getCallerRef()).get(); // this will be object of Main in case its not null.
if( lock != null){    
   synchronized( lock ) {
     lock.notifyAll();
   }
}
```

**Edit** One basic issue in the code you have is that you have justthe single thread. Same thread goes in wait and same thread tries to invoke `notifyAll`. If this thread goes in wait state then there is no thread which can invoke `notifyAll` , this results in application being in hanged state forever. You need to invoke the setupWizard constructor from a separate thread.

**EDIT 2**
there are many issues with your code.

1. You need to have separate thread calling the registerAccount so that notifying thread is different from the waiting thread.
2. Your constructor invokes currently the registerAccount which tries to synchronize on the lock objct but you pass the lock object from main after contructor is invoked.
3. your object on which you wait and on which you invoke notifyall are different objects

Comment: Thanks for your input, thats a lot more clear now. However, I still get the clear-seenthrough window thingy happening :\

Comment: Hope you havenot missed the `.get()` , it will return the actual object wrapped inside the WeakReference ,in case it is not null. Also why you are invoking `dispose()`

Comment: what about dispose , just for checking purpose can you try running the application by commeting `dispose` in the `registerAccount`.

Comment: it doesnt make a difference :\ also i think i figured out a problem with this, check the main post. no solutions yet however

Comment: hey I just observed You only have single Thread. in tge same thread you call the constructor and same thread you make to wait. There is no two threads, the only thread you have you make it to go in wait state, as soon as it goes in wait state it **does not even invoke the notifyall** . This results in your application go in halt forever. You need to perform the setup and invoke the registerAccount in another thread (need to invoke these operations from the run() method of separate thread. )

Answer (score 0):

I really can't tell for sure from the code you posted, but I suspect your situation might be that the SetupWizard is a Frame or Dialog and the code in Main is executed by EDT, so when you put EDT on wait in Main you are freezing your GUI and SetupWizard code cannot execute neither.

I suggest you just use a Modal Dialog for SetupWizard. It will block Main while SetupWizard is visible.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably what it was! I realised meanwhile I can just 'dispose()' of Main while setupWizard is running and bring it back up when that is finished, it basically does the same thing in my case. I didn't want to use a modal dialog because for first part of the setup im inheriting an already existing interface, so it would have been stupid to have to redo ~500 lines of code. Cheers!